# Protect Excel workbook from opening in outside network

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel workbook which I need to share with my client;but need to make sure that it cannot be opened outside of their office network.

How to protect my Excel workbook like this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from by placing it on your own server and restricting access at the IP level, I don't think this can be done.

An easier solution would be to password-protect or encrypt it, and include a graphic or data that has to be downloaded from you, so that you can track where it's opened.